# Добавление столбцов в таблицу

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Задача: Добавить столбцы к таблице. Если количество столбцов == 10, то прекратить добавление и выполнить определенные действия. Вот что я изобрел:

```js
var addCol = document.body;
addCol.onclick = function() {
  var table = document.querySelectorAll('table')[0];
  var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  var col = table.querySelectorAll('td');

  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var newCol = col[i].cloneNode(true);
    rows[i].appendChild(newCol);
    
    if(rows[i].col.length == 10) {
      console.log(rows[i].col.length);  
    }

  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 372px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.b-matrix {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px 25px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  border-right: 2px solid #444;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;*/
}
/*------- [ ] -------*/

.b-matrix_border:before,
.b-matrix_border:after,
.b-matrix__table_border:before,
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #444;
  content: '';
}
.b-matrix_border:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix_border:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:before {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/*----- // [ ] // -----*/

.matrix-name-A,
.matrix-name-B {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.matrix-name-A {
  top: 50%;
  right: -30px;
  margin-top: -13px;
}
.matrix-name-B {
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
.matrix-cell {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
.matrix-cell:hover {
  /*добавить стили*/
}
.matrix-cell:focus {
  border-color: #09d;
  outline: 2px solid #09d;
}
.matrix-cell[disabled] {
  background: #eee;
}
.matrix-cell[disabled]:hover {
  border-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="a">
    <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br />

</section>
```

В итоге, столбцы добавляются, но если я ниже прописываю условие, то происходит какая-то ерунда, а именно - добавляются столбцы только в первую строку таблицы, при этом условие не срабатывает.

Еще один момент: консоль выдает сообщение "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined". Почему?

Просьба подсказать, где я лажаю. Может быть есть какие-то тонкости, которые я не учитываю/не знаю ...?

Comment: _Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined_ - это значит что идет попытка обратиться к свойству _appendChild_ у переменной, в то время, как значение переменной _undefined_

Comment: @Grundy, не совсем понимаю о какой переменной идет речь, если о newCol, то ведь она определина, разве нет?

Comment: В консоли рядом с ошибкой указывается конкретная строка на которой произошла ошибка, более того по ней можно кликнуть и перейти к месту ошибки

Comment: И еще, почему при добавлении условия, или, скажем, console.log (), столбцы добавляются только в первую строку таблицы?

Comment: `rows[i]` - будет _undefined_ если в разметке меньше 10 элементов `tr`

Comment: не виду никаких условий в приведенном коде

Comment: @Grundy, добавил условие.

Comment: И все-таки не понятно, какое условие нужно прописать в цикле, чтобы все работало как надо ...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41494/discussion-between-grundy-and-astor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для добавления ячейки в конец строки, достаточно выбрать последние ячейки в строках, и после каждой вставить новую ячейку.

При этой у ячеек ест свойство `cellIndex` показывающее номер ячейки в строке (отсчет с 0), то есть можно сразу узнать сколько ячеек уже в строке и надо ли добавлять новые.

```js
var addCol = document.body;
addCol.onclick = function() {
  var lastCells = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="a"] td:last-child');
  // если в строке уже 10 ячеек - ничего не делаем
  if(lastCells.length && lastCells[0].cellIndex==9) return;
  
  [].forEach.call(lastCells,function(cell){
    cell.parentNode.insertBefore(cell.cloneNode(true),null);
  })

  if(lastCells[0].parentNode.childElementCount==10){
    // в таблице теперь 10 ячеек в строке
    console.log('10 cells');
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.b-matrix {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px 25px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  border-right: 2px solid #444;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;*/
}
/*------- [ ] -------*/

.b-matrix_border:before,
.b-matrix_border:after,
.b-matrix__table_border:before,
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #444;
  content: '';
}
.b-matrix_border:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix_border:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:before {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/*----- // [ ] // -----*/

.matrix-name-A,
.matrix-name-B {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.matrix-name-A {
  top: 50%;
  right: -30px;
  margin-top: -13px;
}
.matrix-name-B {
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
.matrix-cell {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
.matrix-cell:hover {
  /*добавить стили*/
}
.matrix-cell:focus {
  border-color: #09d;
  outline: 2px solid #09d;
}
.matrix-cell[disabled] {
  background: #eee;
}
.matrix-cell[disabled]:hover {
  border-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="a">
    <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br />

</section>
```

Comment: @Grandy, и снова спасибо.

Comment: Вот только свойство childElementCount не поддерживается IE младше 9 версии. Может быть есть альтернатива?

Comment: @Astor, есть, `childElements.length`

Comment: Grandy, объясни, пожалуйста, вот эту строчку кода - if(lastCells.length && lastCells[0].cellIndex==9) return;
Не понимаю, как lastCells  с нулевым индексом может быть равен девяти, ведь он находится на нулевой позиции.

Comment: @Astor, ответил в чате, дополнительный вопросы по ответу лучше там задавать

Answer (score 0):

А у тебя же элементов tr только 5, а ты идешь в цикле до 10, и получается, что rows[i] когда i > 10 == undefined. Вот код без ошибки:

```js
var addCol = document.body;

addCol.onclick = function() {
  var table = document.querySelectorAll('table')[0];
  var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  var col = table.querySelectorAll('td');

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var newCol = col[i].cloneNode(true);
    rows[i].appendChild(newCol); 
  }
}
```

```css
        body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 372px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.b-matrix {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px 25px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  border-right: 2px solid #444;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;*/
}
/*------- [ ] -------*/

.b-matrix_border:before,
.b-matrix_border:after,
.b-matrix__table_border:before,
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #444;
  content: '';
}
.b-matrix_border:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix_border:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:before {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/*----- // [ ] // -----*/

.matrix-name-A,
.matrix-name-B {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.matrix-name-A {
  top: 50%;
  right: -30px;
  margin-top: -13px;
}
.matrix-name-B {
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
.matrix-cell {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
.matrix-cell:hover {
  /*добавить стили*/
}
.matrix-cell:focus {
  border-color: #09d;
  outline: 2px solid #09d;
}
.matrix-cell[disabled] {
  background: #eee;
}
.matrix-cell[disabled]:hover {
  border-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
  <div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="a">
    <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="matrix-cell" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br />
 
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Немножечко переписал ваш скрипт

```
document.body.onclick = function() {
  var table = document.querySelectorAll('table')[0];
  var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  var allCols = table.querySelectorAll('td');
  var columnsCount = allCols.length / rows.length;

  if (columnsCount < 10) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var newCol = allCols[i * columnsCount].cloneNode(true);
        rows[i].appendChild(newCol);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Делаем что-то другое")
  }
}
```

Он как раз делает то, что вы просили. При клике на странице копирует первую колонку из таблицы.

Comment: Вы просто скопировали мой ответ и добавлены бессмысленные строчки, которые не влияют на результат скрипта.

Comment: @ikerya, эм… вообще-то это основано коде из вопроса. А строчи очень даже не бессмысленные. И тут не только добавление строчек. Вы смотрели, как работает этот код?